# reconstruct audio from cepstrum

Tags: python, signal-processing

i am trying a simple task > calculate the cepstrum of a small audio sample, lift it and do the inverse process to build the audio file back. I obviously made a mistake as it does not work well

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter
import soundfile as sf
import librosa
import IPython.display as ipd# for audio output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # matplotlib is for python graphs and display

# Define the complex cepstrum function
def complex_cepstrum(x, nfft=None):
    if nfft is None:
        nfft = len(x)
    X = np.fft.fft(x, n=nfft)
    logX = np.log(np.abs(X))
    c = np.fft.ifft(logX, n=nfft)
    return c.real, c.imag, np.angle(X)

# Define the liftering function
def lifter(c_real, c_imag, lifter_order=22):
    c = c_real + 1j * c_imag
    c[0] = 0  # Set the DC component to zero
    lifter = 1 + (lifter_order / 2) * np.sin(np.pi * np.arange(len(c)) / lifter_order)
    return lifter * c.real, lifter * c.imag

# Define the inverse complex cepstrum function
def inverse_complex_cepstrum(c_real, c_imag, phase=None, n=None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(c_real)
    logX = c_real + 1j * c_imag
    if phase is not None:
        X = np.exp(logX + 1j * phase)
    else:
        X = np.exp(logX)
    x = np.fft.ifft(X, n=n).real
    return x

# Load an audio sample
x, fs = librosa.load('audio.wav', sr=44100, mono=True)

# Pre-emphasis
preemph = 0.97
x = lfilter([1, -preemph], [1], x)

# Compute the complex cepstrum
c_real, c_imag, phase = complex_cepstrum(x)

# Apply liftering
c_liftered_real, c_liftered_imag = lifter(c_real, c_imag)

# Reconstruct the audio signal
x_reconstructed = inverse_complex_cepstrum(c_liftered_real, c_liftered_imag, phase=phase)

# Write the reconstructed signal to a file
sf.write('audio_rec.wav', x_reconstructed, 44100, 'PCM_24')
```

I note that I have searched quite some time before reaching you here. It generates a huge ammount of (white) noise on top of the audio file which I can't understand where this comes from.

If anyone has a direction where to look, thanks a lot.

P

Comment: what is "wavfile"? you are not including that module

Comment: you are right, was a mistake. used soundfile instead

Answer (score 2):

First, for sure order of operations in `inverse_complex_cepstrum` is reverted.

```
X = np.exp(np.fft.ifft(logX).real)
```

should be

```
X = np.fft.ifft(np.exp(logX)).real
```

Next, since you are doing `np.abs` in cepstrum, you are losing information about signal phase, irrevertibly. I am not sure what you want to achieve and how to deal with that phase. What comes to my mind is caching information about phase and reuse it during inverse operation.

Comment: agreed for the phase, I did change the code

Comment: @pm200107 take a look at cepstrum: `x->fft->log->ifft->c`. Inverse to it should be `c->fft->exp->ifft->x`

Comment: I guess this is what I do, sorry for my mistaken comment (that I deleted):  
```if phase is not None:  
        X = np.exp(logX + 1j * phase)  
    else:  
        X = np.exp(logX)  
    x = np.fft.ifft(X, n=n).real  ```

Comment: @pm200107 if the noise still persists, try removing lfilter and check if without it whole forward-inverse operation is "clean", if not, remove next stage and check